# Check if a list has one or more strings that match a regex

Tags: python, regex, list

If need to say

```
if <this list has a string in it that matches this rexeg>:
    do_stuff()
```

I [found](http://www.cademuir.eu/blog/2011/10/20/python-searching-for-a-string-within-a-list-list-comprehension/) this powerful construct to extract matching strings from a list:

```
[m.group(1) for l in my_list for m in [my_regex.search(l)] if m]
```

...but this is hard to read and overkill. I don't want the list, I just want to know if such a list would have anything in it.

Is there a simpler-reading way to get that answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply use `any`. Demo:

```
>>> lst = ['hello', '123', 'SO']
>>> any(re.search('\d', s) for s in lst)
True
>>> any(re.search('\d{4}', s) for s in lst)
False
```

use `re.match` if you want to enforce matching from the start of the string.

*Explanation*:

`any` will check if there is any truthy value in an iterable. In the first example, we pass the contents of the following list (in the form of a generator):

```
>>> [re.search('\d', s) for s in lst]
[None, <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f15ef317d30>, None]
```

which has one match-object which is truthy, while `None` will always evaluate to `False` in a boolean context. This is why `any` will return `False` for the second example:

```
>>> [re.search('\d{4}', s) for s in lst]
[None, None, None]
```

Comment: Sweet and simple REPL example!